# Upper bound for convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x\in(0,1)$. Consider the sequence

$$
s_{j,k} = x\frac{\left(1-x^{2 j}-2 j (1-x) x^{j-1}\right) x^{k+1}}{(1-x)^2}
$$

I need to find a sequence $\rho_k$ such that

$$
\sup_{j\geq 1}\left|s_{j,k}\right|\leq \rho_k\quad (1)
$$

with

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\rho_k}{k^q}
$$

for some $0\leq q<1$. The idea is that, for large $j$

$$
s_{j,k}\sim \frac{x^{k+2}}{(1-x)^2}
$$

but I miss something to prove formally inequality (1).